# Javascript/ES6 generate nested array from 1 level object

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

i do have an object coming from an API like this:

```
  this.Variations = [
  {
    attributes: [
      {name: "Cor", option: "Preto"},
      {name: "Tamanho", option: "P"},
      {name: "Tecido", option: "Algodao"},
    ],
    id : 1
  },
  {
    attributes: [
      {name: "Cor", option: "Preto"},
      {name: "Tamanho", option: "P"},
      {name: "Tecido", option: "Elastano"},
    ],
    id : 2
  },
  {
    attributes: [
      {name: "Cor", option: "Preto"},
      {name: "Tamanho", option: "M"},
      {name: "Tecido", option: "Algodao"},
    ],
    id : 3
  }, ...
```

and i have to generate a nested array from it, in order to create the experience i need, which is the user selecting attributes one by time, and loading the possible options.

I am struggling with this for a long time now and got nowhere.

I believe I need an array similar to that:

```
array['Preto']['P']['Algodao'] = info;
array['Preto']['P']['Elastano'] = info;
array['Preto']['M']['Algodao'] = info;
```

Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: where is `info` coming from?

Comment: Your `array` is an object with object property `Preto` that has an object property `P` and this has a property `Algodao`. What exactly you need with "nested" array?

Comment: Are the record count within **attributes** property is fixed to 3? or it's dynamic too?

Comment: my array does not exist my friend, i need to generate it like that. Thas is an example.

Comment: The count is dynamic, this is why is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works regardless of the number of items in `attributes` arrays:

```js
var Variations = [
   {
     attributes: [
       {name: "Cor", option: "Preto"},
       {name: "Tamanho", option: "P"},
       {name: "Tecido", option: "Algodao"},
       {name: "Foo", option: "Bar"},
     ],
     id : 1
   },
   {
     attributes: [
       {name: "Cor", option: "Preto"},
       {name: "Tamanho", option: "P"},
       {name: "Tecido", option: "Elastano"},
     ],
     id : 2
   },
   {
     attributes: [
       {name: "Cor", option: "Preto"},
       {name: "Tamanho", option: "M"},
       {name: "Tecido", option: "Algodao"},
     ],
     id : 3
   }];

const getLevelValue = (rec, att, index) => index === rec.attributes.length - 1 ? rec.id : {},
 getData = variations => variations.map(rec => rec.attributes.
  reduce(({acc, current}, att, index) => 
  (current = current ?  current[att.option] = getLevelValue(rec, att, index) : 
   acc[att.option] = getLevelValue(rec, att, index), {acc, current}), 
  {acc: {}}).acc);
console.log(getData(Variations));
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by `info` you meant `id` value, try this approach

```
var output = variations.map( s => ({ [s.attributes[0].option ] : 
     { [s.attributes[1].option ] : 
         { [ s.attributes[2].option] : s.id } } }) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var variations = [{
    attributes: [{
        name: "Cor",
        option: "Preto"
      },
      {
        name: "Tamanho",
        option: "P"
      },
      {
        name: "Tecido",
        option: "Algodao"
      },
    ],
    id: 1
  },
  {
    attributes: [{
        name: "Cor",
        option: "Preto"
      },
      {
        name: "Tamanho",
        option: "P"
      },
      {
        name: "Tecido",
        option: "Elastano"
      },
    ],
    id: 2
  },
  {
    attributes: [{
        name: "Cor",
        option: "Preto"
      },
      {
        name: "Tamanho",
        option: "M"
      },
      {
        name: "Tecido",
        option: "Algodao"
      },
    ],
    id: 3
  }
];

var output = variations.map( s => ({ [s.attributes[0].option ] : { [s.attributes[1].option ] : { [ s.attributes[2].option] : s.id } } }) );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Your anwser must be right! It keeps the same order. Anyway to generate an array instead of object? And would this still work if i have more than 3 levels of nest?

Comment: it does not have to be an array, but if my initial object has just one atribute or more than 3, it collapses.

Comment: You never mentioned that level of nesting needs to be dynamic. You can extend this code to achieve the same. Give it a go and create a new question if you face any trouble doing so. Good luck!

Comment: i am trying to understand how to use .map for that, but is too much confusing for me, anyhow, if you could give me a hand, would appreciate, but if not, thanks anyway.

Comment: nevermind bro, but thanks anyway, really appreciate this community.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and the attributes for a nested object and assign a value at the leaves.

```js
var data = [{ attributes: [{ name: "Cor", option: "Preto" }, { name: "Tamanho", option: "P" }, { name: "Tecido", option: "Algodao" }], id: 1 }, { attributes: [{ name: "Cor", option: "Preto" }, { name: "Tamanho", option: "P" }, { name: "Tecido", option: "Elastano" }], id: 2 }, { attributes: [{ name: "Cor", option: "Preto" }, { name: "Tamanho", option: "M" }, { name: "Tecido", option: "Algodao" }], id: 3 }],
    result = {};

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.attributes.reduce(function (r, b, i, bb) {
        return r[b.option] = i + 1 === bb.length
            ? a.id
            : r[b.option] || {};
    }, result);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hi there nina, i believe your suggestion is the one, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Nina it worked like i expected! The only issue is that the order is reversed, and this is an issue, since it puts 'sizes' in desc order. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: where do you get `sizes` from?

Comment: 'Tamanho' is sizes (portuguese), im sorry. Your solution works, but reverses the entire object. Anyway to keep the same order?

Comment: in which order do you want it? you could use `reduceRight` for iterating from the other side.